# jQuery JSONP Call towards PHP backend: No HTTP response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

**Update IV / Current status:** I've now confirmed trough another question that the character encoding of the file is fine and not the cause of the problem. I've also tested against another server and the error still persists. It does however work towards localhost.
*So to summarize:* JSONP call works towards localhost, but when running against external domains the response from the server is empty (no header / no http response code). When copying the requested URL and inserting it directly in a browser, the output is correct with correct formating (utf-8 / json).

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5SJvp/1/

**Update III:** I'm now able to get it working succesfully on localhost. However, using the exact same code (both client and server) towards my production domain it still fails. The response from the server is "empty" meaning to say it returns no http status code.

**Update II:** After some more debugging I noticed that the response does not include an http status code. This probably is the cause of my problem? I assume this means there is something wrong server side, but I cannot for the life of me see where.

**Update I:** Snip from jQuery where to request seems to halt.

```
// Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );
```

Params (from Firebug)

```
_   1356655864905
callback    jQuery18308375673194150332_1356655863817
p   0522
pl  12
s   false
secret  ##############################
u   request12341299
```

Request (from Firebug)

```
Accept  text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language nb-no,nb;q=0.9,no-no;q=0.8,no;q=0.6,nn-no;q=0.5,nn;q=0.4,en-us;q=0.3,en;q=0.1
Connection  keep-alive
Host    localhost:8888
Referer http://localhost:8888/popup.html
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
```

**Original question:**

I'm struggling with what seems to be a common problem, but I've yet to find a solution. I'm trying to execute a very simple jsonp call using jQuery. The problem is that either a) nothing is happening or b), the response from the server is empty.

I've tried several different approaches, using both the $.ajax method and the $.getJSON method. Both produce the same faulty result. Using the code below nothing happens: Using the Chrome debugger I can see that it simply stops its execution halffway trough the method. However using Wireshark I can see that the client performs the three way handshake and thusly prepars to send data, it just fails to do that.

If I remove the **callback=?** it does execute, however the response is malformed (or at least, I think so since I can only see a response marked with a red line in Firebug).

```
$.ajax({
     url: "http://mydomain.com/asd.php", //"http://localhost:8888/index.php",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     type: 'GET',
     data: {p:p, u:u, s:symbols, pl:pl, secret:secret},
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     async: false,
     success: function(data){
        console.log("What " + data.test); 
     }, 
     error: function(data){
         console.log("failed for some reason");
     }
 });
```

Server code ($callback = $_GET["callback"]

```
<?php header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
.
.
.
$data = array
(
    "message" => $message,
    "status" => $statuscode,
    "length" => strlen($message)        
);

echo $callback . '('.json_encode($data) .')';
exit;       
?>
```

Here is the server response with manually typed input.

```
funcName({"message":"!0b7(cb6Gv40","status":"OK","length":12})
```

Comment: i believe you need the callback=? part. what is the malformed server response? and you should post the server code as well.

Comment: is `funcName` real name of wrapper? Try setting `jsonpCallback` option to match it in `$.ajax` and leave out `callback=?` in url.

Comment: I've added the server code now.
@kennypu I don't know if it's malformed. Firebug simple marks the request in bold red without any HTTP status code or any stated reason.

Comment: @charlietfl No, funcName is just a stand in. I've edited in the server code now.

Comment: Perhaps your response is not valid JSON data format. I have only seen formats like these [{"val":"1"},{"val","2"}] or {"val":"1"}
and not funcName({"val","1"})

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The parentheses and "funcName" is the json_Padding part.

Comment: Could you host your PHP somewhere so one can try to debug it live?

Comment: Sure, 
http://serve.pin2pass.com/?callback=jQuery18305613593256270389_1356983729420&p=0000&u=test&s=false&pl=12&secret=c68f39913f901f3ddf44c707357a7d70&_=1356983731753

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will obviously **NOT** work if you did not set up your SSL certificates properly.

This works properly when I transform the https to http: http://jsfiddle.net/eysEe/

```
var u = "test";
var p = 1234;
var symbols = false;
var pl = 16;
var secret = "c68f39913f901f3ddf44c707357a7d70";

$.ajax({
    url: "http://serve.pin2pass.com?index.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        p: p,
        u: u,
        s: symbols,
        pl: pl,
        secret: secret
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test').text(data.message);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#test').text("SDf");
    }
});
```

You can tell if you have bad SSL installation when "https://serve.pin2pass.com?index.php" leads to a risky page. Maybe you never intended to put it in https mode ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I did not intend to use https in the fiddle, I'm using http for testing (as you say, the certifcate is not valid). However, just so we're clear - all you did was change from https to http? Your example is working, but I can't see the difference between my fiddle and yours (apart from the protocol).

Comment: You're welcome ^_^. The protocol is the only problem. CSRF (Cross-site request forgery) cannot be established without a valid SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to debug this without a jsfiddle/jsbin, so my best suggestion would be to try getting the request to work with fake, static data (just an empty JSON struct, {}, will do).

It seems that the problem might lie in how you are using json_encode, since you write that when you add the callback=? param the response looks mangled. The suggested test will let you diagnose better where the issue lies.

Comment: Using your suggestion I'm now able to get it working on localhost. Very confusing is however that after doing this and adding back the original code ... it worked as intended. All I did was fire a request that got succesfully returned with empty brackets, then removed it and added back the original code.

Comment: That's rather strange, I agree. Is there any chance that with that edit you changed the php file's encoding?

Comment: I initially doubted it since I've created and deployed this project the exact same way I've done previous projects that are up and running. Using Eclipse with the PDT plugin and utf-8 charset. I did however note that when using "file -bi" on the prod. server (running Ubuntu / Apache2) the charset is reported as us-ascii on the problematic file. However, the "file -bi" also reports other php files (working in production) as text/html which doesn't make much sense. But I'll look further into it. As always, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I've now confirmed, unfortunately, that the character encoding is not the cause of the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry that it didn't help. If you could set up a jsfiddle/jsbin it would be much easier to try and debug this.

Comment: Well the problem is that as far as I know, you can't do ajax calls from jsfiddle? At least I didn't get it to work when I initally created this question.

Comment: Why? Since this is a JSONP request there is no problem. Here is a trivial example using my company's API- [JSONP jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YvHX3/)

Answer (score 0):

`callback` is the universal GET param for wrapper function name for the jsonp. When you use `callback=?` in jQuery request, jQuery will parse the `?` into something else with a time stamp so it will be always be a unique value. The API server will wrap the json in this unique function name, and jQuery stores the name  so it can use it to unwrap the response.

Some API's are not flexible and require their own specific name in which case you can use the `jsonpCallback` option in either `$.ajax` or set it globally in `$.ajaxSetup`

See `$.ajax`  API docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've already read trough the doc, but I'm still no closer to understanding why my call is getting dropped / halted. Since I'm not working with an API but rather a custom made back end I don't have the issue regarding hardcoded functions name either.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your code I've set it up locally and everything works as expected:

**test.php :**

```
<?php

$callback = $_GET["callback"];

$data = array
(
    "message" => 'test',
    "status" => 200,
    "length" => strlen('test')        
);

echo $callback . '('.json_encode($data) .')';
exit;
```

**test.html** :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON("http://localhost/test.php?callback=?",
    {
      whatever: 1,},
    function(data) {
      alert("hmm");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Two things that could help you :

1. Not putting the `callback=?` in your call fails because the JSON returned from your server is not valid JSON (due to the parenthesis around your json data). `$.getJSON` will silently fail in this case. If you want to see the error, use `$.ajax` instead.
2. Your problem *might* come from the fact that you're apparently trying to use https here. In Chrome at least, making an AJAX request to an https URL with an invalid certificate (I assume your localhost or test domain doesn't have a valid certificate) just puts an error in the console. The browser never prompts with the "are you sure?" about the certificate.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But as far as I can see you haven't changed anything from the original code? I've edited the first post on what line inside jQuery the request halts.

I'm hoping to use https for the final result, but I've tried without it to no avail - same result.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, can you try using 'Fiddler' to debug the call? Perhaps that empty server response isn't that empty after all.
Or maybe your server has some strange security settings, and checks the REFERRER header to block out external calls?

If you can give a full url to your app I could test it for you =)

Answer (score 0):

So, with the new fiddle it was much easier to work. This is a working sample of your call-

```
var u = "test";

var p = 1234;
var symbols = false;
var pl = 16;
var secret = "c68f39913f901f3ddf44c707357a7d70";

$.ajax({
    url: "https://serve.pin2pass.com/index.php",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        p: p,
        u: u,
        s: symbols,
        pl: pl,
        secret: secret
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    aync:true,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#test').text(data.message);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.log("failed for some reason");
    }
});​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YeqXN/)

I hope I am not missing something here. The only change I had to do is in the request url, from

```
https://serve.pin2pass.com?index.php
```

to
    https://serve.pin2pass.com/index.php

Hope this solves it.